# Icon conventions for "Ignore" and "Ignore All"

Tags: gui-design, icons, guidelines

Does anyone know if there are conventionally used (best practice) icons for "ignore" and "ignore all" (for example, like in spellcheck). Thank you.

Comment: Generally icons suggestions are off topic here.

Comment: Thanks Mayo, sorry for posting here... where would it be appropriate to ask this question? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anna. While there are a few places you could ask, any replies while be purely opinion. Icons do not improve usability and require past knowledge to have any meaning. Your best solution is text, followed by existing examples and user testing. In the end, there is no convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about "ignore" icons, but "dismiss" and "mark as read" icons are used a lot elsewhere. Facebook uses an icon for "Mark as read" notification actions and text to "Mark all as read", while Google uses icon for both actions. Doesn't seem to be a best practice scenario, you can get the idea from those examples.